# What is the numeric value of FMFD_RETURNUPDATEDIMGMIMES in dwMimeFlags param of FindMimeFromData()?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, constants, mime-types

I need to pinvoke the [`FindMimeFromData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107.aspx) function with the `FMFD_RETURNUPDATEDIMGMIMES` flag included in the `dwMimeFlags` parameter. How do I find out the numeric value of this constant so that I can use it in C#?

I have little experience with pinvoke, so maybe I'm missing something obvious. Is there a generally accepted way of dealing (in managed code) with constants defined in unmanaged API? Especially when the API description on MSDN only mentions constant names, not their values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not found a solution but if this is the full flag list and if it respect standard I think values are:

```
0 - FMFD_DEFAULT
1 - FMFD_URLASFILENAME
2 - FMFD_ENABLEMIMESNIFFING
4 - FMFD_IGNOREMIMETEXTPLAIN
8 - FMFD_SERVERMIME
16 - FMFD_RESPECTTEXTPLAIN  
32 - FMFD_RETURNUPDATEDIMGMIMES
```

This is just an idea.. hth!

**update**

I've also found those lines of code confirm my idea...

```
#if (_WIN32_IE >= 0x0602)
    #define FMFD_ENABLEMIMESNIFFING     0x00000002L
    #define FMFD_IGNOREMIMETEXTPLAIN    0x00000004L
#endif
#define FMFD_SERVERMIME                 0x00000008L
```

Comment: You're right, thanks. Curiously, MSDN says that `dwMimeFlags` is "**One of** the following required values", not their combination. A documentation bug I suppose.

Comment: One more question about the code snipped you added - where does it come from? Is it something from MS? It looks suspicious, as it defines those constants as `long`s, while the `FindMimeFromData` API says `DWORD dwMimeFlags`.

Comment: I've found it googling... cannot find the site now... try using those values I think this snippet is for a different language! If it helped you don't forget to sign as accepted! ;-)

Comment: found it: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ajPxBMAwe_oJ:owbuilder.malakovi.cz/snapshot/h/nt/urlmon.h+FMFD_IGNOREMIMETEXTPLAIN+%2B4+FMFD_SERVERMIME+%2B8&cd=3&hl=it&ct=clnk&gl=it&source=www.google.it